# How to skip page if request response is 404 or 505

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-3.6

I wrote a scraper in python.  Unfortunately, when the scraper encounters a `404` or `505` page it stops working.  How can I skip those pages in my loop in order to avoid this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
c = int(40622)
a = 10
for a in range(10):
    url = 'https://example.com/rockery/'+str(c)
    c = int(c) + 1
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print(url)
    print(c)
    time.sleep(5)
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    name = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'name-hyperlink'})
    name_final = name.text

    name_details = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post-text'})
    name_details_final = name_details.text
    
    name_taglist = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post-taglist'})
    name_taglist_final = name_taglist.text

    name_accepted_tmp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'accepted-name'})
    name_accepted = name_accepted_tmp.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post-text'})
    name_accepted_final = name_accepted.text

    print('q_title=',name_final,'\nq_details=',name_details,'\nq_answer=',name_accepted)
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Here is the error I encounter when I hit a `404` or `505` page:

> error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "scrab.py", line 18, in
>
> name_final = name.text
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the status code of the response, if it is not 200 (ok) you can skip it by going to the next iteration in your loop with a `continue` statement:

```
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200: #could also check == requests.codes.ok
   continue
```

Comment: @JunedRajbhara, welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this is definitely the correct answer.  However, you should try this on your end and see if it works for you.  If it does, please click the green check-box to accept this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: i tried but it will stop working and get the error                                        File "stack.py", line 27, in <module>
    question_accepted_answer = name_accepted.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post-text'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: @JunedRajbhara do you still get an error? I updated my response to address if you do, although if you don't i'll remove the updates.

Comment: yup it work but i need to replace all my final veriable after the if condition it cause the main problem.

Comment: @TheoretiCAL i did                                                                             
if name != None and name_details != None and name_taglist != None and name_accepted_tmp != None:
  name_accepted = name_accepted_tmp.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post-text'})
  name_final = name.text
  name_details_final = name_details.text
  name_taglist_final = name_taglist.text
  name_accepted_final = name_accepted.text
 else:
  continue